# Is there a way of adding a drop down list to Wordpress registration form?

Tags: php, wordpress, registration, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to add a dropdown list to the registration form on my Wordpress site. But I can not work it out (I'm very new to PHP).

Example:

```
Select
- Red
- Blue
- Green
```

If the user was to select green, that information also needs to link to the users profile page.

Answer (score 2):

There are a series of actions you need to add in order to do this which is probably why you're struggling. Full code below:

EDIT : Made the code more DRY

Setup the options you want in your dropdown

```
// Set the values we want in dropdown
function get_dropdown_options(){
  $dropdownOptions = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue'];
  return $dropdownOptions;
}
```

Add the field to frontend registration form

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'unbranded_registration_form' );
function unbranded_registration_form() {

    $year = ! empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ? intval( $_POST['colour_field'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="colour_field"><?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a colour', 'unbranded' ) ?><br/>
        <select name="colour_field" id="colour_field">
        <?php
          foreach (get_dropdown_options() as $option) {
            echo "<option>$option</option>";
          }
        ?>
        </select>
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Decide how you're going to deal with any errors:

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'unbranded_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function unbranded_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'colour_field_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please choose a colour.', 'unbranded' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'unbranded_user_register' );
add_action( 'edit_user_created_user', 'unbranded_user_register' );

function unbranded_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'colour_field', intval( $_POST['colour_field'] ) );
    }
}
```

Add the same registration field to the admin side of the site

```
/**
 * Back end registration
 */

add_action( 'user_new_form', 'unbranded_admin_registration_form' );
function unbranded_admin_registration_form( $operation ) {
    if ( 'add-new-user' !== $operation ) {
        // $operation may also be 'add-existing-user'
        return;
    }

    $year = ! empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ? intval( $_POST['colour_field'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Information', 'unbranded' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="colour_field"><?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a colour', 'unbranded' ); ?></label> <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( '(required)', 'unbranded' ); ?></span></th>
            <td>
      <select name="colour_field" id="colour_field">
        <?php
          foreach (get_dropdown_options() as $option) {
            echo "<option>$option</option>";
          }
        ?>
      </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

And deal with errors in the same way here (You could reuse function above if you wanted, but have kept it separate in case you need to do some different validation)

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'unbranded_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function unbranded_user_profile_update_errors( $errors, $update, $user ) {
    if ( $update ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'colour_field_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please choose a colour.', 'unbranded' ) );
    }
}
```

Show the field in admin:

```
/**
 * Back end display
 */

 // Hooks near the bottom of profile page (if current user)
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'unbranded_show_extra_profile_fields' );

// Hooks near the bottom of the profile page (if not current user)
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'unbranded_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function unbranded_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Information', 'unbranded' ); ?></h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
          <th><label for="colour_field"><?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a colour', 'unbranded' ); ?></label></th>
          <td>
            <select name="colour_field" id="colour_field">
              <?php
                $colour = get_the_author_meta( 'colour_field', $user->ID ) ;
                foreach (get_dropdown_options() as $option) {
                  echo "<option ";
                  if ($colour == $option) {
                    echo 'selected';
                  }
                  echo ">$option</option>";
                }
              ?>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

Allow field to be updated on admin area

```
// Hook is used to save custom fields that have been added to the WordPress profile page (if current user)
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields' );
// Hook is used to save custom fields that have been added to the WordPress profile page (if not current user)
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_profile_fields' );
function update_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
  if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ){
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'colour_field', $_POST['colour_field'] );
  }
}
```

To show the same field on the frontend user profile, add this to your template file:

```
$user = get_current_user_id()
get_user_meta($user->ID, 'colour_field', false);
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help!!! This almost works, everything is there except on the admin area. It says "Choose a colour" but with nothing next to it, as if nothing was selected.

Comment: Going to try this on a local dev site when I get a minute, will update answer after that, it's always worked for me...

Comment: @Jamie Have just updated the code and tested, fully working now. Replace what I had before with all of this. Also, you can now set the options in the dropdown from one place using the first piece of code in the array.

Comment: What an absolute legend! I will add the code to the site tonight, but im sure it will work just fine!!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my site. The drop down is showing on both the form and the back end but if I select for example Green on the form, the backend shows the first option (red).

Comment: How frustrating, will have another look in the morning, I didn't check the registration, just assumed it was working. Will revert back to you tomorrow hopefully

Comment: I am going to recreate the form with a plugin, so I'm not wasting anyones time. Not sure why I didn't do it to begin with. Thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it does not save to the database is that you use an intval for a string. Change from

```
function unbranded_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'colour_field', intval($_POST['colour_field'] ) );
    }
}
```

to

```
function unbranded_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['colour_field'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'colour_field', $_POST['colour_field']);
    }
}
```